# Props send after third click on element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with sending information from one component child to parent and from parent to other component. There is 3 components main (App.js), and two child (MoviePoster.js and MovieDescription.js). In App.js we have state named ID. I send function with setState to MoviePoster where I use it in onClick. Function seting id to our state. App.js send props with id to MovieDescription. In MovieDescription I use API to download information about film based on his ID. Clicking on MoviePoster should change ID and send to MovieDescription, after that MovieDescription should render information about this film. I must click three times on MoviePoster to render new information about film and i can't understand why it's working after third click and doesn't work after first click. Here is my code:

App.js

First I tried to save all information from API to couple of states. But in the end it causes inifinite loop with rendering the elements. So I change state to global variables.
Second I tried to put downloading from API to Component Life Circle Methods like in code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.updateId = this.updateId.bind(this)
  }
  state = {
    response: '',
    post: '',
    responseToPost: '',
    id: 438808
  };

  updateId = (id) => {
    this.setState({id: id})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <MoviePoster updateId = {this.updateId} />
      <MovieDescription id = {this.state.id} />
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

MoviePoster.js

```
class MoviePoster extends React.Component{
    state = {
        images: [],
        title: []
    }

    handleImgClick = (id) => {
        this.props.updateId(id);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getMovie();
    }
    getMovie = ()=>{
        axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=332654c71ccbb479020bcc047eaa43e8&language=en-US&page=1&region=pl')
        .then(res=>{
            this.setState({
                images: res.data.results.slice(0,4)
            })

        })  
    }

    render(){
        const { images } = this.state;
        const posters = images.map( image => {
                return(
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleImgClick(image.id)} className='poster-con'key={image.id}>
                        <div className='poster-s-con' >
                            <img className="poster responsive-img" src ={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${image.poster_path}`} alt='img'/>
                            <h5 className='movie-title'>{image.title}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                )
            })

        return(
            <div className='movie-big-con white-text'>
                <div className='movie-small-con'>
                <div className='movie-con'>{posters}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

    )}

};

export default MoviePoster;
```

MovieDescription.js

```
let data = {};
let data1 = {};
class MovieDescription extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                data = json;
            });
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}/credits?api_key=${api_key}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                data1 = json;
            });
    }
    componentWillUpdate() {
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                data = json;
            });
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}/credits?api_key=${api_key}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                data1 = json;

            });

}


    render() {
              return(
                       <div>{data.overview}</div>
                       <div>{data.runtime}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to click once on poster and have rerendered component MovieDescription with new content download from API. I dont have idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best part in react is state which you are not utilizing it in MovieDescription component so move data and data1 variables under component state so that whenever you do setState the component will re render with updated data. With your current MovieDescription component code though you do fetch calls assign data to variables won’t re render the component because you are overriding a variable so it won’t trigger re render.

Also use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount method. As you know componentWillMount is deprecated in react v16 version.

Here is the updated MovieDescription component code

```
   class MovieDescription extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data:{},
                data1: {}
            }
        }
       componentDidMount() {
     fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({data : json});
        });
               fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}/credits?api_key=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({data1: json});
        });
}
componentWillUpdate() {
       fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({data : json});
        });
       fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.id}/credits?api_key=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({data1 :json});

        });
     }
     render() {
          return(
                   <div>{data.overview}</div>
                   <div>{data.runtime}</div>
          );
     }
 }
```

Comment: After use your way to code this. The usage of memory in browser rise to 80-90% and processor 50% so I think it is caused by some infinite loop. If we're using two times setState in one method like componentWillUpdate() we rerender on first setState but there is the second so rerender once again and use setState over over rendering again. I use console.log in render method and looks on the console when my log appears in infinity.  The data still change only after fews click on the poster.

Comment: Because you are using componentWillUpdate which isn’t needed in your case. You have to remove componentWillUpdate completely

Comment: But a method ComponentDidMount() runs only once so when we fetch the next data to show in page ?

Comment: What is the scenario? In which scenario/case you get next data?

Comment: When we clicked on MoviePoster element we change ID state in App. App passed to MovieDescription this ID and there we fetch data from API. When we click on another MoviePoster it should fetch next movie data from API in oour MovieDescription component.

Comment: If that is the case then you should fetch data in MoviePoster component but not in MovieDescription component. MovieDescription should be a pure component. As you said you are clicking in MoviePoster component so do fetch in that event handler function and set the response into state and pass that state down to MovieDescription. This is how you should do in more control way

Answer (score 0):

in MovieDescription, put the data objects in the state. when you get the json back from the fetches uses `setState({})` to update the data. I think that should fix your problem. Ideally you would do all of this in the main component and pass the data as props to the child components. That way you don't have to worry about the states in three objects, just one.

Comment: I refactor my code in the way you write here but unfortunately it causes infinite render loop too.
`